# Attached file cannot be Viewed

Tags: php

I am sending e-mails through php mail(). In that, I am able to receive simple(text) mails. When I attach the file, I am receiveing the attachment in the e-mail, but when I try to view it, the file is always blank, even when its a PDF Format!!!. Please help me out. The code of my send-mail page is as follows:

```
include_once("db_connect.php");
session_start();
error_reporting(16);
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');//Getting values from Session
$tot = $_SESSION['$tot'];
$from = $_SESSION['from'];
$message = $_SESSION['message'];
$subject = $_SESSION['subject'];
$full_nm = $_SESSION['firstnm']." ".$_SESSION['lastnm'];
$temp_passwd = $_SESSION['e_pwd'];
$email_use = $_SESSION['email'];

function send_mail($to, $message, $subject, $from, $temp_passwd, $full_nm, $email_use)
{
    $message_org      = nl2br($message);
    $mail             = new PHPMailer();
    $body             = $message_org;
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->AddAttachment("Uploads/file.pdf");
    $mail->ContentType = "mutlipart/alternative";
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->Username   = $from;
    $mail->Password   = $temp_passwd;
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $full_nm);
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $address = $to;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $address);

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
        $err_send = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
        else
    {
        $err_send = "";
    }
}
foreach($tot as $to_trim)
{
    $to = trim($to_trim);
    send_mail($to, $message, $subject, $from, $temp_passwd, $full_nm, $email_use);
    echo $err_send;
}

The function AddAttachment in class.phpmailer.php is as follows:

public function AddAttachment($path, $name = '', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/octet-stream') {
try {
  if ( !@is_file($path) ) {
    throw new phpmailerException($this->Lang('file_access') . $path, self::STOP_CONTINUE);
  }
  $filename = basename($path);
  if ( $name == '' ) {
    $name = $filename;
  }

  $this->attachment[] = array(
    0 => $path,
    1 => $filename,
    2 => $name,
    3 => $encoding,
    4 => $type,
    5 => false,  // isStringAttachment
    6 => 'attachment',
    7 => 0
  );

} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  $this->SetError($e->getMessage());
  if ($this->exceptions) {
    throw $e;
  }
  echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
  if ( $e->getCode() == self::STOP_CRITICAL ) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to submit an edit that fixes your formatting, but you should read the help about how to format code.  Adding <br>s all over the place makes it difficult, especially when they're inconsistent.

Comment: @jedwards: I did a fix, but I suddenly lost my editing privileges http://pastebin.com/CTVRdwhm

Comment: I submitted an edit, once its reviewed it should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

When you do $mail->AddAttachment("Uploads/file.pdf");
If you put the add attachment in an "if file exists add attachment" clause, does the file not get attched? Im thinking "Uploads/file.pdf" isnt sufficient pathing.

Comment: File is getting attached. But cannot be viewed when Downloaded. Text files can be viewed. I think that its something related to Encryption and Decryption of the attachment.

Comment: Can you try sending the mail with your code, but comment out the contenttype line?

Comment: Ya sure. Please give me your email id.

Comment: OH, I didnt mean send to me, I meant adjust your code and send without the specifcying the content type - as it maybe by manually doing so its getting confused.

Comment: Oh, Ok. Well, I tried that too. But thats the same result I am getting. Only text files can be sent, not any other files. :(

Comment: Are you usually sending PDFs? If so, have you considered specifying the attachment type , eg "Application/PDF"

Comment: I have tried out most of the attachment types. But that is also not working. Even size is getting increased.

Comment: You mean the mail is bigger than you expect or the actual attachment size is misrepresented? If its just the mail size is bigger thats normal. Is there any chance the pdf isnt properly received before calling this script, eg its truncated due to lack os space, or file size limits ?

Comment: The actual attachment size is getting increased. And the pdf is received properly. I mean, even if I open it directly in my web browser (gmail gives this facility) it is showing me increased file size, with no data. It gives error like that the data is insufficient for this file to open...like that sort of. The attachment size I am sending is around 40-50 kB size. I don't think that should be a trouble for any of yahoo or gmail or hotmail.

Comment: Have you looked at the raw email? Have you tried sending an image instead?

Comment: Yup...the text is coming. I have tried sending the jpeg(jpg), pdf, txt, doc files. The file I am getting in the E-mail, but the files except txt are not able to be viewed in the browsers as well as when downloaded and opened from the Computer. I am able to open the txt files.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation for this class](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial) you should be able to specify a relative path for that file.

Try preceding that line with a PHP test to see whether the file actually exists:

```
// Change this
$mail->AddAttachment("Uploads/file.pdf");

// To this...
$attachment = "Uploads/file.pdf";
$mail->AddAttachment($attachment);

// And then to this
$attachment = "Uploads/file.pdf";
if(!file_exists($attachment) && !file_exists(getcwd().'/'.$attachment)
{
    die(sprintf("attachment: %s does not exist", $attachment));
}
$mail->AddAttachment($attachment);
```

I included a middle step just to show you my thinking.

I haven't tested the `if` statement, but the idea is to make sure the `$attachment` variable is either a valid absolute (first part) or relative (second part) path.

Comment: File is getting attached. But cannot be viewed when Downloaded. Text files can be viewed. I think that its something related to Encryption and Decryption of the attachment. Anyways, this is a code that would be helpful to me to confirm attachments.

Thanks a lot for this.